# Continuous clicking sound on the jack

Tags: headphone-jack

While the phone is powered on, and I plug something in the jack of the phone, I hear a continuous clicking sound, with the frequency of about 4 times per second, on the right speaker. The left speaker plays the audio as it should.
I don't have a mono device to see how it behaves with it...
The phone's speakers do not have this problem, or the Bluetooth headset.
The sound is identical, as far as I can tell, to the sound (almost?) any audio device makes when it's plugged in (and/or out?).

Phone: Lenovo A800
Android version: 4.0.4

The issue doesn't happen on my Nexus 7.
Happens with headsets, earphones, external speakers... Pretty much everything in the jack.
I chose to post the issue here because I have found various similar issues with other Android devices around the Internet, but no working solution.

Is there any known cause for this? Any solution..?

---

My brother just bought a new headset, and there's no clicking sound with it.
I looked at the jacks and there seems to be no difference.
Any ideas...?

Comment: i have this same sound on my lenovoa800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I forgot about this.

My brother came to me and jammed the jack in as far as it could physically go.
The problem was fixed...

Answer (score -1):

The jack component on the board inside is failing. Common problem. Fixable. Caused by overheating

Comment: How can it be fixed?

Comment: Wasn't the problem. The real issue was the jack resisting the insertion too much. Enough to make me think it was all the way in. In fact, it wasn't.